# FaunaDB: How to create index for arbitrary length-array field

Tags: faunadb

Is there a way to create an index for an array property of a document, so that I can `Match` the document based on any value in the array?

For example, assuming a document looks something like

```
{ data: { ips: ['192.168.1.1', '::ffff:c0a8:101'] } }
```

then I'd like to have an index `documents_by_ip` s.t. I can retrieve that document with *either* `192.168.1.1` *or* `::ffff:c0a8:101`.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to answer this question before even posting it. There are no extra steps required, just adding a field that is an array to the index terms will do exactly what I wanted to ~~~

```js
CreateIndex('documents_by_id', { terms: [{ field: ['data', 'ips'] }] })
```